# Rewrite rule for drupal login page, force https

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, https

I'm struggling writing a rewrite rule for a drupal login page which needs to accessed under https.

```
RewriteRule ^/?(/user) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

so baiscally i need to redirect /user to https:// (base url) /user

Can anyone provide a pointer as to how to do this please?

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule /(user|admin) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R]
```

Answer (score 1):

How about using the [Secure Login module](http://drupal.org/project/securelogin)?